# How do I get calls organized by phone number?

Tags: contacts, history

Hi I would like to organize my recent call list by number instead of the default sorting by date. Or I would like to see the list of previous calls & messages with a phone number. 
Currently I am just going back in history to see if I received a call from someone in the past couple days. It will be great if order by phone number/contact option is available

I am using Iphone 5, iOS 8.4.0

Android phones are able to do this. It is quite useful

Comment: That does not currently appear to be an option in iOS.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, please include hardware and software information, e.g. iPhone 4s, iOS 7.1.2, when asking questions as not all features are available in all models and iOS versions.

That said, I do not believe you have a choice, at least I don't on my iPhone in the Phone app, however I have an app on my MacBook Pro (also available for Windows) called [iMazing](https://imazing.com) that I can sort my call history by All and Contact and by Date, Contact, Duration and Number.  I can also export to Text or CSV files.

There may be a third-party iOS App that can do what you want right on the iPhone.  [callLog](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/callog/id327883585?mt=8) may be a possibility.

Comment: It should be mandatory to include hardware/OS/software details. I'm sure there's a meta question for that, of course...

Comment: Nice answers here: http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1141/i-think-system-specifications-should-show-as-signature/1147. Maybe it is not such a good idea after all. It's just tiresome to ask for details on almost half of the questions.

Comment: I need an app on the phone, not on the desktop

Comment: @adam, Did you miss where I said "There may be a third-party iOS App that can do what you want right on the iPhone. callLog may be a possibility." which included a hyperlink to callLog?